# Unsure how to test whether a variable is present or not in Query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Based on whether the value I obtained from the previous PHP file is present in the query, I need to execute and print a different set of queries. In my code below, I first check whether song_id I received from the previous page is present in songs. If it is, then I need to print a different set of queries. So I planned to write an if statement to check whether the result of my previous query is empty(If it is empty, then it is not present and vice versa). My code doesn't seem to work. How can I go about accomplishing this task?

```
  $stmt = $pdo ->prepare('SELECT song_id from concerts
                                WHERE :variable1 IN
                                (SELECT song_id from songs)');
        $stmt->execute([':variable1' => $my_id ]);

        //EXIT POINT
        if (empty($stmt) { 

        $stmt = $pdo ->prepare......
        //Different Set of queries


        } else   {

        $stmt = $pdo ->prepare..... 
        //Different Set of queries
    {
```

Comment: have you tried the isset function?

Comment: Your SQL isn't valid, by the way.  You are missing a closing parenthesis around the subquery following `WHERE :variable1 IN`.

Comment: I missed that while copy pasting the same @ Tim Biegeleisen. I tested all my queries and they work fine

Comment: @CésarEscudero I tried using if(isset($stmt)) and it still isn't working. It repeatedly printing the same result for everything